# Laravel godaddy deployent file upload not working

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, deployment, hosting

I recently hosted on Godaddy and I got it working until my program tries to upload a file in laravel public folder.

The site is pretty much working but I can't upload a file using the post methods and services below 
here is the angularjs service / checkout my services that works fine at localhost

```
services.factory('Game', ['$http', function($http){
return {

        get:function(){
            return;
        }

    ,   post:function(documentData){
                return $http(               
                { method: 'POST',
                  url: 'public/Game/store',
                  // headers:   {    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                  data: documentData
         });
        }
    ,fbImageUpload:function(docData){
                return $http(               
                { method: 'POST',
                  url: 'public/Game/create',
                  // headers:   {    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                  data: docData
         });
        }
};
```

}]);

and I am calling the service like this

```
       docData={"uprofile":$scope.picture.picture.data.url,
                "gameName":$scope.gameName,
                "userId":$scope.picture.id};
       console.log(docData);
       drawText("Please wait  ... ",50,50,"mainCanvasD");
       Game.fbImageUpload(docData).success(function (res){


                drawUrlImage("game/"+$scope.gameName+"/profile/back.jpg",0,0,540,320,"mainCanvasD");
                console.log("profile picture");
                drawUrlImage(res.data,30,130,180,180,"mainCanvasD");
                console.log("fb profile");

                drawUrlImage("game/"+$scope.gameName+"/right/"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+".jpg",320,130,180,180,"mainCanvasD");
                console.log("emperor profile");
                $scope.enableShare=true;
                $scope.loading=false;   

       }).error(function (res){
                console.log("fb Image upload to server werajale failed");
                console.log(res);
       });
```

my laravel backened code

```
     */
public function create(Request $request)
{   
    $file = $request->uprofile;

    // Open the file to get existing content
    $data = file_get_contents($file);

    // New file
    $new = "game/".$request->gameName."/play/".$request->userId.".jpg";

    // Write the contents back to a new file
    file_put_contents($new, $data);
// $url = $request->uprofile;
//     $file = file_get_contents($url);        
    // $file->move("game/".$request->gameName."/play/",$request->userId.".jpg");
    // $image = Image::make($request->uprofile)->save("game/".$request->gameName."/play/".$request->userId.".jpg");
    return Response(["data"=>"game/".$request->gameName."/play/".$request->userId.".jpg"]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

   try {

        file_put_contents( "game/".$request->gameName."/play/".$request->gameName.$request->userId.".jpg",
                 // base64_decode($request->image) 
                  base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $request->image))
            );

             return Response(["status"=>"true","data"=>"http://localhost/ezone/public/"."game/".$request->gameName."/play/".$request->gameName.$request->userId.".jpg"]);

        // }else {
        //     return Response(["success"=>false,"message"=>"Invalid Image argument"]);
        // }    
   } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Response(["status"=>false,"message"=>$e.""]);
   }


}
```

I got it working on my local installation of laravel, probably its a permission thing but can't get it done on [goddady.com](http://godaddy.com)

How could I change the permission to my public folder to upload files to my public folder by my program.

Comment: Does it give you an exception?

Comment: it responds nothing jut nothing

Comment: Check your error logs, it may either be a permission issue or maybe a blacklisted function.  Or it can be a problem with the file name.  You may need to be more specific with the path.  But your first step is to look at the error logs to see what went wrong.

Comment: where are the logs, does goddady provide logs

Comment: I believe it has a directory within your site folder. A logs folder.  You can probably use the file manager to find it though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100273/discussion-between-dagm-fekadu-and-miltoxbeyond).

Comment: I would ask if it's too late to change GoDaddy?Untunately it's too late i guess..